# Определить сереализованный объект

Tags: java, преобразование, преобразование-типов

Есть клиент-сервер которые общаются между собой сереализованными объектами. Возник вопрос как определить какой объект пришел на сервер, чтоб правильно его распознать?

Клиент, который случайным образом отправляет 3 варианта объекта

```
List <Integer> lInt = new ArrayList<>();
List <String> lStr= new ArrayList<>();
List <Object> lObj= new ArrayList<>();
ObjectOutputStream sOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
sOut.writeObject(lInt);
sOut.writeObject(lStr);
sOut.writeObject(lObj);
```

Сервер, который получает объект и десериализует его. Но как мне понять какой именно пришел объект чтоб его потом прокастить например так lInt = (List "Integer")obj?

```
List <Integer> lInt = new ArrayList<>();
List <String> lStr= new ArrayList<>();
List <Object> lObj= new ArrayList<>();
ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(7800);
Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
ObjectInputStream sIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Object obj = null;
while ((obj = sIn.readObject())!=null){ 
       lInt = (List <Integer>)obj; ////Ошибка если объект не List <Integer>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что надо передавать также и тип данных.

Я рекомендую создать базовый класс для запросов, например:

```
public class MyRequest{
   public static enum RequestType {int, string, obj};
   private RequestType mType;
   private  Object mData;

   public MyRequest(RequestType  type, Object data){
      mType = type;
      mData = data;
   }

   public RequestType  getRequestType(){
      return mType;
   }

   public Object getData(){
      return mData;
   }
}
```

Тогда будет так:

```
MyRequest intRequest = new MyRequest(RequestType.int, new ArrayList<>());
ObjectOutputStream sOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
sOut.writeObject(intRequest );
```

А на сервере:

```
List <Integer> lInt;
MyRequest request;
ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(7800);
Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
ObjectInputStream sIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Object obj = null;
while ((obj = sIn.readObject())!=null){ 
     request = (MyRequest)obj; // приводит сначала к типу базового реквеста
     switch(request.getRequestType()){
        // а потом в зависимости от типа запроса приводим к нужному классу
        case RequestType.int:
        lInt = (List <Integer>)request.getDate();
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Чего то не додумался до этого